# not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.datetime'

Tags: python

i want to compare two time parameters, of which one is of type datetime.datetime and another of datetime.time.
current_time is of datetime.datetime type wheareas other two are datetime.time

```
        print(type(current_time))
        print(type(start_time))
        print(type(end_time))

        <class 'datetime.datetime'>
        <class 'datetime.time'>
        <class 'datetime.time'>
```

I've to use this condition

```
if start_time < current_time < end_time:
```

tried converting datetime.datetime to datetime.time and vice versa but it didnt work out, plz help me out on this

Comment: You likely want to get the `current_time.time()` part of `current_time` to compare against the others

Comment: What should it mean to compare a point in time with date and time to a time of the day (which day?)?

Comment: Can you change `current_time` so you're getting it the same way as the other two time values, so they are all the same type?

Comment: "tried converting datetime.datetime to datetime.time and vice versa but it didnt work out".  What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your goal is to determine if the current time (regardless of date) falls between a given date-agnostic start and end time (e.g. for "business hours" for a company open 9-5 every day, `start_time` represents `0900`, and `end_time` represents `1700`, and the date doesn't matter), you'd just change:

```
if start_time < current_time < end_time:
```

to:

```
if start_time < current_time.time() < end_time:
```

which will extract the `datetime.time` object from `current_time` (ignoring the `date` component) for the purposes of the test (conveniently, because you're already using chained comparisons, it only does this once, and reuses it for both parts of the test).

Note: It's unusual for time ranges to be exclusive on the end points (why should 9:00:00.0 not be in the range, when 9:00:00.000000001 is in the range?), so you might want to change the comparison operators from `<` to `<=`. Won't typically matter for programmatically constructed times, but if you're accepting times from users (or typing the manually for testing), humans tend to round off, so those edge cases will get hit more often.

Answer (score 0):

Compare `datetime.datetime` object to `datetime.time` object may have some issues.

Image the following example:

```
A = "January 3rd 23:59:00"
B = "January 4rd 01:00:00"
```

Probably you want your code to say that B is greater than A, right?
But if compare only 23:59 (from A) to 01:00 (from B), you'll get the opposite.
That's the problem comparing datetime to time.

I suggest you only use `datetime.datetime` objects.

If you still want to do this, you can just use `current_time.time()`.